# Changing pictures every 5 seconds using jquery in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please help me I am new in jQuery.
here is my code:

```
<img src="default.jpg" />
<img src="a.jpg" />
<img src="b.jpg" />
<img src="c.jpg" />
```

I want to change the picture from default.jpg to a.jpg. then a.jpg to to b.jpg and so on, every 5 seconds. using jquery. Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your specific programming-related question?

Comment: Please read the FAQ. Show some effort and people will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<img id="thisImg" alt="img" src="images/img0.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //prepare Your data array with img urls
        var dataArray=new Array();
        dataArray[0]="images/img1.png";
        dataArray[1]="images/img2.png";
        dataArray[2]="images/img3.png";
        dataArray[3]="images/img0.png";

        //start with id=0 after 5 seconds
        var thisId=0;

        window.setInterval(function(){
            $('#thisImg').attr('src',dataArray[thisId]);
            thisId++; //increment data array id
            if (thisId==3) thisId=0; //repeat from start
        },5000);        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you @archios this help me alot. i just want to appear the image with slow fade in. is it possible?

Comment: Just modify the inner setInterval function to change the images using jq animations (like fadeIn [link](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [link](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). You can also use [link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) jq animate function. For fadeOut fadeIn the changed code would look like: $('#thisImg').fadeOut(function () {
               $('#thisImg').attr('src', dataArray[thisId]);
               thisId++;
               if (thisId == 3) thisId = 0;
               $('#thisImg').fadeIn();
           }); Remember to preload images (google: preload images jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Set this in head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

jquery code

```
setInterval(function(){
$('#img').remove();
$('body').prepend('<img src="urlimgs" id="img">');
},5000);
```

I didn't understand what you want but it is so basic! You need learn more about jquery..
You can improve this code.. it is only a example