# Script to display image1, and after (random ms) show image2 and stop

Tags: javascript, php, image, random

I've been looking around, and there are a lot of questions (and answers) about changing image after a few seconds, but I didn't find anything that works for me.

What I want;

A script, PHP or Java (prefer PHP to hide function from users) that displays an image1 and after a few milliseconds RANDOM (500-5000) it changes it to image 2, and STOPS THERE.

I have no idea how to create this, so any help would be appreciated..

UPDATE:  basically I want to load a certain image after the system has displayed a "loading" ring in (RANDOM) milliseconds.
And I need to do it on several images on the same page

Comment: I see no reason to do this in PHP. Just use Javascript (with JQuery) and after a while hide the first image and show the second. Javascript is much better at timing this than PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing pictures every 5 seconds using jquery in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639606/changing-pictures-every-5-seconds-using-jquery-in-php)

Comment: You will not need PHP or Java (both are backend technologies) to achive this. You only need JavaScript on client (browser) side. For instance, you can use setTimeout() with a random time, and then change the image on the callback.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id='imageDiv'>
    <img src='path_to_img/file.jpg' />
</div>
```

You can add this code on document.ready.

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var millisecondsToWait = 500;
    setTimeout(function() {

       $('#imageDiv').html(" <img src='path_to_img/file2.jpg' />");

    }, millisecondsToWait);

});
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to add that this is HTML and Javascript code that depends on JQuery?

Comment: true, @KIKOSoftware let me update it

Comment: Ok. I also think the transition will not be a good as it can be. You remove the first image before the second image can be loaded. It is better to load both images and use JQuery's `show()` and `hide()`.

Comment: I might add that it needs to be run simultaneously on several smaller images (therefore the random request in time)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: good suggestion

Comment: there could be  number of a number of ways and improvements. I thought he just needs to show the first image and then after certain moments, he needs to load the second one.

Comment: yes example is fine according to question @DanyalSandeelo

Comment: @AdamLarsson if you need repetition tha's what you need then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639606/changing-pictures-every-5-seconds-using-jquery-in-php

Comment: this link can also help @AdamLarsson :  https://codepen.io/kman/pen/dXjpoX

Comment: Ok, maybe a rewrite of the question